# Audio booster for pc

Tags: audio

Is there any software which can be used to boost the audio output from the PC. Mostly I want it to work on browser, for eg. to watch videos on youtube with boosted sound.
I am using Windows XP SP3

Comment: Please define 'boost' a bit more precisely. Do you mean louder or more bass or anything else?

Comment: More Volume is the priority, other things like bass are add-ons :)

Comment: If you've already turned the volume to maximum in Windows and in the Youtube controls, you probably need a physical audio amplifier for your headphones, or for your speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the program called [SX Fidelity Amplifier](http://www.soundgenetics.com/sxfa_overview.html).

SX Fidelity Amplifier is suitable for everyone who wants enhanced audio from a digital source. Use SX Fidelity Amplifier for:

- PC applications.
- Music Services.
- Streaming Internet Radio.

If not buying, just reinstall after the trying period expired.

Good luck.

Comment: That worked. Do you know any other software, which are opensource or free?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windows XP is a lot more limited than Vista/7 which can do this out the box quite easily.

You can try to see if your driver software came with any advanced options such as artificial boost or loudness equalization... apart from this, your best bet is to simply turn your speakers up or buy more powerful/louder ones.